# Setting Custom cookie and user-agent values in swagger

Tags: cookies, swagger

We are using swagger for api documentation.

I'm facing an issue on tryit out. Basically the rest endpoints which we indent to call from swagger requires 
Cookie(ex: cookie : token=xxxxx;) and User-Agent(User-Agent:custom values;) parameters.

But when I try to set this parameter
Cookie is not send as part of the request.
User-Agent is being overridden by browser values. I tried on firefox and chrome both.

I did tried search online but didn't find suitable answer solve my issue, There were suggestion to set 
useJQuery: true and withCredentials: true to set the cookies, but non worked fine.

Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 0):

As presented on their website:

> In OpenAPI 3.0 terms, cookie authentication is an API key that is sent
>   in: cookie. For example, authentication via a cookie named JSESSIONID
>   is defined as follows:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
...
# 1) Define the cookie name
components:
  securitySchemes:
    cookieAuth:         # arbitrary name for the security scheme; will be used in the "security" key later
      type: apiKey
      in: cookie
      name: JSESSIONID  # cookie name
```

And then at the endpoint level:

```
paths:
     /users:
        get:
          security:
            - cookieAuth: []  # note the arbitrary name defined earlier
          description: Returns a list of users.
          responses: 
            '200':
              description: OK
```

For `swagger: "2.0"` you can define cookie authentication like this:

```
securityDefinitions:
  cookieAuth:
    type: apiKey
    name:
      Cookie # this is actually the Cookie header which will be sent by curl -H
    in: cookie
```

Referencing it at the endpoint is done the same way as for OpenAPI 3.